# Android(Linux)'s mount(8) effect different process by local shell and adb

Tags: android, linux

I want to create a encrypting filesystem by encfs(Android's FDE or FBE can't encrypt single directory),but it doesn't work well when I execute the command by local shell(JuiceSSH):
`encfs --no-default-flags --public --stdinpass /data/home/MediaStore-e /data/media/0/MediaStore -- -o uid=1023,gid=1023,umask=002 #1023 is media_rw's ID`
Only JuiceSSH can access the /data/media/0/MediaStore what I want instead of the old directory(in other words,the true MediaStore).And the other applications(not only Java applications,and also adb etc.) don't think it is a mountpoint:
`adb shell
shell@oneplus3:/ $ su
shell@oneplus3:/ # mountpoint /data/media/0/MediaStore
shell@oneplus3:/ # /data/media/0/MediaStore is not a mountpoint`

In local shell(JuiceSSH):

`oneplus3 ~ # mountpoint /data/media/0/MediaStore
oneplus3 ~ # /data/media/0/MediaStore is a mountpoint`
And /system/bin/sdcard(the application which provides /storage/emulated/) can't access it,so I can't read my data from /storage/emulated/0/MediaStore.
But If I execute the command above by adb,it will work well.
I use this script to find the processes which know the directory is a mountpoint:
`for dir in /proc/*;do
    if [ -e $dir/mounts ];then
        if grep -q MediaStore $dir/mounts;then
            cat $dir/cmdline
            echo
        fi
    fi
done`
When I run `encfs --no-default-flags --public --stdinpass /data/home/MediaStore-e /data/media/0/MediaStore -- -o uid=1023,gid=1023,umask=002` by local shell,the script print this:
`com.sonelli.juicessh
/data/user/0/com.sonelli.juicessh/files/bin/arm/pie/bash--rcfile/data/user/0/com.sonelli.juicessh/files/share/bashrc
su0-c/data/data/com.sonelli.juicessh/files/bin/arm/pie/bash--rcfile/data/home/.bashrc
/data/data/com.sonelli.juicessh/files/bin/arm/pie/bash--rcfile/data/home/.bashrc
/data/bin/encfs--no-default-flags--public--stdinpass/data/home/MediaStore-e/data/media/0/MediaStore---ouid=1023,gid=1023,umask=002`

When I do that by adb,it prints so many lines that I can't put them here,but almost all processes are in them.And other applications (such as music player)can access the data what I want.
The adb shell and local shell run as the same user and group,and own the same secure context(u:r:su:s0),I even tried to clear environment variables,and `setenforce 0`,I got the same result as before.How can I fix it?I can't use adb to do it every time I reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by myself,so I answer myself question to share my solution.
This reason why other processes can't access the mount tree what I want is than they are in different mount namespace.ADB's name space is same as `/sbin/init`,but JuiceSSH(or other terminal application created by zygote64) is in another mount namespace create by clone(2),so you can't access the mount tree by other application even as root.
Solution:
1.
If your `su` supports `--mount-master` option,just use it.
2.
Write a shell script which was executed by /system/bin/sysinit * on boot,so it is in the same mount namespace as init(1).It read commands from a FIFO and excute it.It is like this:

`#!/system/bin/sh
mknod /data/.global_fifo p
while true;do
        eval "$(cat /data/.global_fifo)"
done`

Don't forget set correct mode and secure context for it.

- sysinit is a application,it execute /system/etc/init.d/* just like most of linux distribution,it was installed on cyanogenmod 13.0.You can write one by yourself and add it into /init.rc.)